# Does $exists:false use an index?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

We have the following use case: Due to protocolling reasons we do not remove deleted or updated records from the database. We `$set` their `deleted` field to the date/time when they were updated/deleted and create a new record( if updated). So all "current" records do not have the `deleted` field". All indexes on current records look like this:

```
{ 
    field_a: 1, 
    field_b: 1, 
    ..., 
    deleted: 1 
}
```

A query concerning current records looks like this:

```
find( {
    field_a: "...", 
    field_b: "...", 
    deleted: { $exists: false}
} )
```

Because I am not sure if the `{$exists: false}` uses the index, I have added a field `current` set to `true` to all current fields (those without `deleted`) and I changed the indexes to:

```
{ 
    field_a: 1, 
    field_b: 1, 
    ..., 
    current: 1 
}
```

and my query to:

```
find( {
    field_a: "...", 
    field_b: "...", 
    current: true
} )
```

Can anyone tell me if the latter case is really the better one? Or do they perform indetically and I can spare the additional `current` field?

Thanks for any hint.

Comment: Did you use `explain` with one of your queries to check whether it uses the index? Is it a sparse index?

Comment: No, I have not checked via explain yet. I thought there might be a general answer on this question. And no, it is no sparse index, because sparse:true does not work with compound indexes.

Comment: It's always best to check `explain` as I've seen a lot of developers surprised by MongoDB's index usage patterns.